# How to avoid whitespace being ignored on sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to match my input with 3 variable types: an integer, a float and a string.

```
char *input = "1 5.456 oxygen\0";

int i = sscanf(input, "%d %f %[^\0]", &id, &dens, name);
if (i != 3)
    break;
```

This works great if input does contain all these 3 types and I use the value returned by sscanf in order to check this.

But if input is missing the integer at the beginning such as:

```
char *input = " 5.456 oxygen\0";
```

the variable **i** will still be equal to 3 because sscanf will match id with 5 and dens with .456.

What is the best way to use sscanf so it checks for whitespaces between the required types (at least one or more whitespaces).

Comment: No best way using `scanf()`. Your best option is to use `fgets()` and a parser (which can be as simple as `strtol()`, `strtod()`, `strcpy()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char *input = "1 5.456 oxygen";
char c1, c2;
if (sscanf(input, "%d%c%f%c %[^\n]", &id, &c1, &dens, &c2, name) != 5 ||
    !isspace(c1) || !isspace(c2)) break;
```

Please note that it's impossible to insert a `\0` to the scanf format, so you need something else, e.g. `\n` there. This works if the input doesn't contain a `\n`.